# List of people in Tanach

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, tanach, historical-figures

Can I find anywhere a comprehensive list of every single person that is mentioned in Tanach. Including somewhat "biographical" information, who they were, family, what they did, how they fit into Tanach, etc.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest [Ishei Hatanach / Encyclopedia Of Biblical Personalities
Anthologized from the Talmud, Midrash, and Rabbinic writings by Yishai Chasidah](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/ISHL.html). It's an Artscroll product.

Comment: There's also a Hebrew version, I think

Comment: This is a good one.  I found it on someone's bookshelf once and spent an entire Shabbath drawn into it.

Answer (score 13):

I found this website online: http://www.tanakhprofiles.org/showentries.php.

Comment: Nice find. [15]

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia has two great lists.  Very thorough - just filter out the New Testament...
No midrash though - it's very pshat.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_biblical_figures,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_major_biblical_figures