# Book of TaNaKhic names with their meanings

Tags: product-recommendation, names, tanach

I hope this is the right forum for a search/request like this.

A few months ago - unfortunately, I don't remember the context in which it arose - I stumbled across a terrific book on HebrewBooks.org that listed virtually every name appearing in TaNa"Kh with its meaning and source.

One name I specifically remember appearing in the book is אהליאב. It described the name as meaning that HaShem (G-d) is our tent (i.e. our protector) and brought a description of who Aholiav was.

Does anyone know of a book or books like this? I would be truly grateful!

Comment: Wow! The book called "Anshei Shem" that I found focuses only on the ancestry of *Ge'onim*. I don't think that's what you want. Any other possible book name that you can surmise?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it was not called Anshei Shem. Sorry for that red herring.

Comment: See [here](http://tora.us.fm/tnk1/dmut/ToknLfiDmutHkl.html) for an apparently relatively thorough list of names, but I dont think it includes reasons for names.

Comment: @Lee Errors happen for good reasons. You inadvertently directed me to an interesting book. And, you got me in the mood for Matjes herring, too :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what book you're referring to as it's sitting on the bottom of my shelf at home, but offhand I couldn't remember what it was called. I did some googling to see if I could find the title, and came across some other options (as well as [a different question on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22467/list-of-people-in-tanach) that might also answer your question).

There is an English Artscroll book called [Ishei Hatanach](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/ISHL.html) that might also help help with what you're looking for.

Update: Turns out, the book I was thinking of was Michlol Hama'amarim Vehapisgamim, a book about phrases and their sources. I don't actually have the book of names in my house, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. The book I found, however, was freely available on the Internet. IIRC, it was available on HebrewBooks.org

Comment: Any update, @Salmononius2?

Comment: @Lee Unfortunately, as per my update, I was mistaken about the book I was thinking of. Family members of mine do remember seeing a book on names, but I haven't seen it around.